# Failed to generate Table diagram -- RelationShipDiagramError (SchemaSpy - GraphViz)

Tags: java, mysql, graphviz, schemaspy

Trying to create the DB schema ER Diagram using the below command but unable to generate the ER diagrams sue to some issue with graphViz configurations. schemaSpy is creating the html based file of all the tables and .dot files also being created successfully in specified output directory. But those then .dot files are not being converted into ER diagrams to be added in .html to display.

**Versions :**

1. Java : v8
2. schemaSpy : v6.1.0
3. graphViz : dot - graphviz version 7.0.2 (20221119.0110)
4. mysql : mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar

**Command :**

**java -jar .\schemaspy-6.1.0.jar -t mysql -dp C:\mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar -db datagenerator_poc -gv 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz' -host 127.0.0.1 -port 5000 -s mysql -u root -p staging123 -o /SchemaSpy**

**Logs**

```
SchemaSpy generates an HTML representation of a database schema's relationships.
SchemaSpy comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
SchemaSpy is free software and can be redistributed under the conditions of LGPL version 3 or later.
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/

INFO  - Starting Main v6.1.0 on DESKTOP-O4DE6AA with PID 10936 (C:\Users\Ascend\Desktop\ATS Codebase\demo\src\main\resources\lib\schemaspy-6.1.0.jar started by Ascend in C:\Users\Ascen
d\Desktop\ATS Codebase\demo\src\main\resources\lib)
INFO  - The following profiles are active: default
INFO  - Started Main in 1.314 seconds (JVM running for 1.814)
INFO  - Starting schema analysis
INFO  - Connected to MySQL - 8.0.31
INFO  - Gathering schema details
Gathering schema details.........................................(34sec)
Connecting relationships.........................................(14sec)
Writing/graphing summary.INFO  - Gathered schema details in 14 seconds
INFO  - Writing/graphing summary
INFO  - Graphviz rendered set to ''
..ERROR - RelationShipDiagramError
Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\summary\relationships.implied.compact.dot
ERROR - RelationShipDiagramError
Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\summary\relationships.implied.large.dot
.ERROR - Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\orphans\help_keyword.1degree.dot
Failed to generate Orphan diagram
ERROR - Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\orphans\help_relation.1degree.dot
Failed to generate Orphan diagram
ERROR - Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\orphans\plugin.1degree.dot
Failed to generate Orphan diagram
ERROR - Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\orphans\replication_group_configuration_version.1degree.dot
Failed to generate Orphan diagram
ERROR - Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\orphans\time_zone.1degree.dot
Failed to generate Orphan diagram
ERROR - Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\orphans\time_zone_leap_second.1degree.dot
Failed to generate Orphan diagram
ERROR - Failed to produce diagram for: \SchemaSpy\diagrams\orphans\time_zone_name.1degree.dot
Failed to generate Orphan diagram
.....(1sec)
Writing/diagramming detailsINFO  - Completed summary in 1 seconds
INFO  - Writing/diagramming details
..Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.schemaspy.output.diagram.DiagramException: Failed to generate Table diagram
        at org.schemaspy.output.diagram.DiagramFactory.generateTableDiagram(DiagramFactory.java:71)
        at org.schemaspy.output.html.mustache.diagrams.MustacheDiagramFactory.generateTableDiagram(MustacheDiagramFactory.java:44)
        at org.schemaspy.output.html.mustache.diagrams.MustacheTableDiagramFactory.generateTableDiagrams(MustacheTableDiagramFactory.java:80)
        at org.schemaspy.SchemaAnalyzer.generateHtmlDoc(SchemaAnalyzer.java:426)
        at org.schemaspy.SchemaAnalyzer.analyze(SchemaAnalyzer.java:260)
        at org.schemaspy.SchemaAnalyzer.analyze(SchemaAnalyzer.java:123)
        at org.schemaspy.cli.SchemaSpyRunner.runAnalyzer(SchemaSpyRunner.java:98)
        at org.schemaspy.cli.SchemaSpyRunner.run(SchemaSpyRunner.java:87)
        at org.schemaspy.Main.main(Main.java:55)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.schemaspy.output.diagram.DiagramException: Dot missing or invalid version
        at org.schemaspy.output.diagram.graphviz.GraphvizDot.generateDiagram(GraphvizDot.java:193)
        at 
org.schemaspy.output.diagram.DiagramFactory.generateTableDiagram(DiagramFactory.java:68)
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: "Dot missing or invalid version" << Is Graphviz really installed?  Type "dot -V" on the command line and see what happens.  If Graphviz is not installed, go here: http://www.graphviz.org/download/

Comment: "graphViz : dot - graphviz version 7.0.2 (20221119.0110)"  << not the "real" Graphviz,  just a library interface between Java & Graphviz

Comment: graphviz is already installed and we can verify it using dot -V.

Comment: try this change to command line: -gv 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz\bin  << add bin directory.  Also on command line echo %path%

Answer (score 1):

SchemaSpy 6.1.0 and earlier had more strict version constraint, this was relaxed in 6.2.0 where it only prohibits use of 2.31 due to a bug i think.

So getting 6.2.0 should allow the usage of graphviz version 7

Answer (score 0):

You may try this instead:

download graphviz-install-2.49.0 https://graphviz.org/download/